# Detecting the iPhone from jQuery

Tags: jquery, iphone

I know browser-detection is supposed to be taboo, but I'm out of ideas.

I have a website that I want to be nice and full-featured when running on a full-sized computer and simple to use when on an iPhone (or other smart phone).  What's the right thing to do here?

Comment: you want to make a responsive website ? ^^

Comment: @Awea -- I don't understand the question.  Aren't all websites responsive?

Comment: can you check 
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/best-way-to-detect-handheld-device-in-jquery

whether it will be useful

Comment: @Malvolio take a look at this article http://www.splashnology.com/article/how-to-make-a-website-for-all-devices-responsive-web-design/2439/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you can do it with simple javascript

```
function isiPhone(){
    return (
        (navigator.platform.indexOf("iPhone") != -1) ||
        (navigator.platform.indexOf("iPod") != -1)
    );
}
if(isiPhone()){
   alert('iPhone detected');
}
```

Comment: I was thinking about this, but it seemed a bit hackish.  Is this the "right" thing?

Comment: no its not, this is the way to check it, if there is jquery plugin or functionality this will be behind it.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using JQuery? Sure you are! Who isn't, right? Put this in a file called jquery.browser.mobile.js and then reference it.

```
(function (a) {
jQuery.browser.iDevice = /ip(hone|od|ad)/i.test(a);
})(navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera);
```

This will allow you to check for specific instances that you are on an Apple product.

```
if ($.browser.iDevice) {
    // do something exciting
}
```

The reason you'd want to do something like this, is because Apple products fire touch events and not click events. So you might want to hook up handlers to elements differently on Apple products.

Comment: Am I using jQuery?  If I am not, the title of my question is a little odd.

Comment: Sorry I was talking to you and the rest of the community. My solution above is JQuery specific. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Well.. I don't completely understand the question, so I will answer what I understood.

To find the browsers that are iPhone, you will use the javascript in the page to get the navigator.userAgent . The useragent has unique info to iPhone. You can look through it and find it out that way. To see how the iphone useragent differs from a PC user agent, go to whatsmyuseragent.com from both, and you will see the different useragents.